# Proper way to create nested objects in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to create an array of nested objects.  I am following an example from a book that does the following:

```
      // Creates the Schema for the Features object (mimics ESRI)
      var Phone = new Schema({
          number: { type: Number, required: false },
          ...
          personId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}
        }
      );

      // Creates the Schema for the Attachments object
      var Person = new Schema({   
         name: { type: String },  
         phones: [Phone]
        }
      );

  var Person = mongoose.model('Person', Person);
```

Which works just fine when storing multiple Phone #'s for a person.  However I am not sure if there is a good/fast way to get a Phone object by _id.  Since Phone is not a mongoose model you cannot go directly to Phone.findOne({...});  Right now I am stuck with getting a person by _id then looping over that persons phones and seeing if the id matches.

Then I stumbled upon this link:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Is one way more right than the other?  Currently when I delete a person his/her phones go away as well.  Not really sure that works with 'populate', seems like I would need to delete Person and Phones.

Anyone want to attempt to explain the differences?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is that if you need to independently query Phones, then you should keep them in a separate collection and use `populate` to look them up from `People` when needed.  Otherwise, embedding them is typically a better choice as it simplifies updates and deletion.

When using an embedded approach like you are now, note that Mongoose arrays provide an [`id`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_documentarray_MongooseDocumentArray-id) method you can use to more easily look up an element by its `_id` value.

```
var phone = person.phones.id(id);
```